# Which test player had 99.9 average in his test career?

Tags: cricket, trivia, statistics, records

Which test player has 99.9 average in his test career and in last match of his career he was out on 0 ? As if he had just one score in his last inning then his average would have became 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Sir Donald Bradman](https://www.cricbuzz.com/profiles/5945/sir-donald-bradman)***, an Australian batsman was the player who finished his playing career with *[99.94 average in 52 matches and 80 innings](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/282910.html)*.

And he needed [just four runs](https://bleacherreport.com/articles/1881688-top-10-batsmen-by-average-in-test-cricket#slide10) from his final-ever Test match innings to finish with an average of exactly 100.

> "...the great Australian needed just four runs from his final-ever Test match innings against England at the Oval in 1948 to finish with an *average of exactly 100*, only to miss a googly from Eric Hollies and be bowled for a two-ball duck."

[Last match report.](https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/8918/england-vs-australia-5th-test-australia-in-england-1948)