# Which ODI player has average of 99.8?

Tags: cricket, trivia, statistics, records

Which ODI player has 99.8 average in his  career and in last match of his career he was out on 0 ? As if he had just one score in his last match then his average would have became 100.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which test player had 99.9 average in his test career?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/20465/which-test-player-had-99-9-average-in-his-test-career)

Comment: Not a duplicate as asked, this question is about one-day internationals, the suggested foliate is about Test cricket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've gotten Don Bradman's Test average of 99.94 mixed up. No player has an ODI average near 99. The highest, having played a minimum of 20 innings, belongs to Ryan ten Doeschate of the Netherlands with an average of 67.

Answer (score 3):

No player with a reasonable number of innings has an ODI average remotely close to 99, or even above 70.

You have misheard or misremembered the details of such a statement being made about Don Bradman, whose **Test** average was 99.**94**.

He required only four runs from his last innings to achieve exactly 100 average, but instead was bowled for a two-ball duck.

Comment: [Players with a small number of innings and high averages](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=2;orderby=batting_average;template=results;type=batting)